# AND exit code in BASH

Tags: bash, exit, status

I am monitoring websites for availability and using curl command to test for 200 status code.

All URLs are contained in a file. So far so good
What I want to achieve is if all URLs are online then exit 0; If any of the URLs are offline exit 1;
How to achieve this in bash?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post the code of what you have tried. Please also read the documentation here on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this (where 200 - status code).

```
ANSWER=`curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" google.com | grep -c 200`
if [[ $ANSWER == "1" ]];then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I already have the above code but would like to apply it to all my URLs which I have listed in a file. What I'd like to achieve is that for every URL listed if all of them are online (return code of 200), then exit 0 and if ANY of the URLs are offline, then exit 1. (Please note ANY upper case). Thank you